# Unix : find a string with grep -Rn

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I want to find the string `$foo['bar']` in a directory, with the command `grep -Rn` . But no matter what I try, I can't find out what caracter use to avoid regex.

```
user@server$ grep -Rn $foo['bar'] /lib              // obviously don't work

user@server$ grep -Rn "$foo['bar']" /lib            // don't work
user@server$ grep -Rn `$foo['bar']` /lib            // don't work
user@server$ grep -Rn $foo\['bar'\] /lib            // don't work
```

I have to use `grep -Rn` command, not another one. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the [ ] signs, use this:

```
grep -Rn "\$foo\['bar'\]" /lib
```

Note in this context escaping the initial dollar sign is not necessary, but I find it's clearer that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 grep -Rn "$foo\['bar'\]"
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
On sh/bash: grep -Rn "$foo\['bar'\]" /lib
On csh/tcsh: grep -Rn ""\$foo"\['bar'\]" /lib
```